# How to check if there's any error on the file VS Code extension

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm creating a VS Code extension and I want to know how can I check if there is any syntax, typescript or eslint error (any red snake on the file).

[image: File with syntax error]

I already built an extension and have a activate(context) function, but I'm not sure where can I find this using the vscode lib.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case you are interested in getting all generated diagnostics in VS Code. [Diagnostics](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/programmatic-language-features#provide-diagnostics) indicate problems in the code.

You can get all diagnostics in the opened editors by using the [`getDiagnostics`](https://vshaxe.github.io/vscode-extern/VscodeLanguages.html#getDiagnostics) method:

```js
const allDiagnostics = vscode.languages.getDiagnostics();
```